# Retrofit: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path

Tags: android, retrofit2

Trouble to read JSON string from Android retrofit.

### This is my JSON

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "Data Found.",
    "company": [
        {
            "SUPP_ID": "4",
            "SUPP_CODE": "CO_000004",
            "CO_ID": "1",
            "CO_NAME": "Carrots",
            "SUPP_NAME": "Chalakudy Suppliers",
            "SUPP_SHORT_NAME": "CS",
            "SUPP_MOBILE_1": "987654321",
            "SUPP_MOBILE_2": "+1 ",
            "SUPP_PHONE_1": "(456) 123-4561",
            "SUPP_PHONE_2": "",
            "SUPP_EMAIL": "chalakudi@gmail.com",
            "SUPP_ADDR_1": "Chalakudi",
            "SUPP_ADDR_2": "",
            "SUPP_ADDR_3": "",
            "SUPP_ADDR_4": "",
            "SUPP_ADDR_5": "",
            "SUPP_CITY_ID": "1864",
            "SUPP_CITY_NAME": "Chalakudi",
            "SUPP_STATE_ID": "19",
            "SUPP_STATE_NAME": "Kerala",
            "SUPP_COUNTRY_ID": "101",
            "SUPP_COUNTYR_NAME": "India",
            "SUPP_DF_PT_ID": "2",
            "SUPP_PT_CODE": "Debit",
            "SUPP_CR_UID": "1",
            "SUPP_CR_DT": "2019-05-06 15:40:07",
            "SUPP_UP_UID": "1",
            "SUPP_UP_DT": "2019-05-06 15:41:41",
            "SUPP_FRZ_YN": "0",
            "SUPP_IS_DELETED": "0"
        },
        {
            "SUPP_ID": "3",
            "SUPP_CODE": "CO_000003",
            "CO_ID": "1",
            "CO_NAME": "Carrots",
            "SUPP_NAME": "Aluva Suppliers",
            "SUPP_SHORT_NAME": "Aluva",
            "SUPP_MOBILE_1": "+91 9876543210",
            "SUPP_MOBILE_2": "+919876543210",
            "SUPP_PHONE_1": "(456) 123-123_",
            "SUPP_PHONE_2": "",
            "SUPP_EMAIL": "aluva@gmail.com",
            "SUPP_ADDR_1": "aluva",
            "SUPP_ADDR_2": "",
            "SUPP_ADDR_3": "",
            "SUPP_ADDR_4": "",
            "SUPP_ADDR_5": "",
            "SUPP_CITY_ID": "1849",
            "SUPP_CITY_NAME": "Aluva",
            "SUPP_STATE_ID": "19",
            "SUPP_STATE_NAME": "Kerala",
            "SUPP_COUNTRY_ID": "101",
            "SUPP_COUNTYR_NAME": "India",
            "SUPP_DF_PT_ID": "1",
            "SUPP_PT_CODE": "Credit",
            "SUPP_CR_UID": "1",
            "SUPP_CR_DT": "2019-05-06 15:37:39",
            "SUPP_UP_UID": "1",
            "SUPP_UP_DT": "2019-05-06 15:38:00",
            "SUPP_FRZ_YN": "0",
            "SUPP_IS_DELETED": "0"
        },
        {
            "SUPP_ID": "2",
            "SUPP_CODE": "CO_000002",
            "CO_ID": "1",
            "CO_NAME": "Carrots",
            "SUPP_NAME": "Angamaly Suppliers",
            "SUPP_SHORT_NAME": "AS",
            "SUPP_MOBILE_1": "+91 6543216540",
            "SUPP_MOBILE_2": "+1 ",
            "SUPP_PHONE_1": "(456) 123-4560",
            "SUPP_PHONE_2": "",
            "SUPP_EMAIL": "as@gmail.com",
            "SUPP_ADDR_1": "6, Aluva Main Road\r\nAngamaly",
            "SUPP_ADDR_2": "",
            "SUPP_ADDR_3": "",
            "SUPP_ADDR_4": "",
            "SUPP_ADDR_5": "",
            "SUPP_CITY_ID": "1851",
            "SUPP_CITY_NAME": "Angamaly",
            "SUPP_STATE_ID": "19",
            "SUPP_STATE_NAME": "Kerala",
            "SUPP_COUNTRY_ID": "101",
            "SUPP_COUNTYR_NAME": "India",
            "SUPP_DF_PT_ID": "1",
            "SUPP_PT_CODE": "Credit",
            "SUPP_CR_UID": "1",
            "SUPP_CR_DT": "2019-05-02 10:55:46",
            "SUPP_UP_UID": "1",
            "SUPP_UP_DT": "2019-05-06 15:38:17",
            "SUPP_FRZ_YN": "0",
            "SUPP_IS_DELETED": "0"
        },
        {
            "SUPP_ID": "1",
            "SUPP_CODE": "CO_000001",
            "CO_ID": "1",
            "CO_NAME": "Carrots",
            "SUPP_NAME": "Koratty Suppliers",
            "SUPP_SHORT_NAME": "KS",
            "SUPP_MOBILE_1": "+91 9876543210",
            "SUPP_MOBILE_2": "+1 ",
            "SUPP_PHONE_1": "(987) 654-3210",
            "SUPP_PHONE_2": "",
            "SUPP_EMAIL": "koratty@gmail.com",
            "SUPP_ADDR_1": "4/2, Ernakulam High way,\r\nKoratty",
            "SUPP_ADDR_2": "",
            "SUPP_ADDR_3": "",
            "SUPP_ADDR_4": "",
            "SUPP_ADDR_5": "",
            "SUPP_CITY_ID": "1940",
            "SUPP_CITY_NAME": "Koratty",
            "SUPP_STATE_ID": "19",
            "SUPP_STATE_NAME": "Kerala",
            "SUPP_COUNTRY_ID": "101",
            "SUPP_COUNTYR_NAME": "India",
            "SUPP_DF_PT_ID": "1",
            "SUPP_PT_CODE": "Credit",
            "SUPP_CR_UID": "1",
            "SUPP_CR_DT": "2019-05-02 10:41:16",
            "SUPP_UP_UID": "1",
            "SUPP_UP_DT": "2019-05-02 10:43:35",
            "SUPP_FRZ_YN": "0",
            "SUPP_IS_DELETED": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

### This is my Pojo

```
public class ApiResponse {

    public boolean error;
    public String message;

    @SerializedName("company")
    public List<Company> companyList;

}

class Company {

    @SerializedName("SUPP_ID")
    public int suppId;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_CODE")
    public String suppCode;

    @SerializedName("CO_ID")
    public String coID;

    @SerializedName("CO_NAME")
    public String coName;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_NAME")
    public String suppName;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_SHORT_NAME")
    public String suppShName;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_MOBILE_1")
    public String suppMobile1;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_MOBILE_2")
    public String suppMobile2;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_PHONE_1")
    public String suppPhone1;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_PHONE_2")
    public String getSuppPhone2;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_EMAIL")
    public String suppEmail;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_ADDR_1")
    public String suppAddr1;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_ADDR_2")
    public String getSuppAddr2;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_ADDR_3")
    public String suppAddr3;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_ADDR_4")
    public String suppAddr4;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_ADDR_5")
    public String suppAddr5;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_CITY_ID")
    public String suppCityId;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_CITY_NAME")
    public String suppCityName;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_STATE_ID")
    public String suppStateId;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_STATE_NAME")
    public String suppStateName;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_COUNTRY_ID")
    public String suppCountryId;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_COUNTYR_NAME")
    public String suppCountryName;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_DF_PT_ID")
    public int suppDfPtId;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_PT_CODE")
    public String suppPtCode;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_CR_UID")
    public int suppCrUid;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_CR_DT")
    public String suppCrDt;
    //"2019-05-06 15:40:07"

    @SerializedName("SUPP_UP_UID")
    public int suppUpUid;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_UP_DT")
    public String suppUpDt;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_FRZ_YN")
    public int suppFrzYn;

    @SerializedName("SUPP_IS_DELETED")
    public int suppIsDeleted;

}
```

Comment: please add the code where the json is read.

Comment: Can you check what your server is responding with ? Probably what you are getting is an object instead of an array.

Comment: You are expecting multiple ApiResponses with `List<ApiResponse>` but it seems, with the string you posted, there is only one api response, which is an object, and no array.

Comment: public interface ApiInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("index.php")
    Call<List<ApiResponse>> getSupplier(@Field("action") String action);

}

Answer (score 4):

With the following code you expect something else from the json, then you actually get.

```java
public interface ApiInterface { 
   @FormUrlEncoded @POST("index.php") 
   Call<List<ApiResponse>> getSupplier(@Field("action") String action);
 }
```

change it to:

```java
public interface ApiInterface { 
   @FormUrlEncoded @POST("index.php")
   Call<ApiResponse> getSupplier(@Field("action") String action);
 }
```

and you are good to go :)

---

#### Explanation:

With the return type `Call<List<ApiResponse>>` you "tell" Retrofit that the result you expect, will be an array/list. So Retrofit also expect the incoming json to be an array.

So this would be the json, retrofit expects from your notation:

```
[
  {"error": false,
    "message": "Data Found.",
    "company": [...]
  },
  {"error": false,
    "message": "Data Found.",
    "company": [...]
  }
  ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you sunchezz now its works fine. Thanks alot.